# Are there any ways to reinforce Paper Birds?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

So the party is toying with the idea to contact a nomadic NPC who's continuously in motion as far as they've ever seen, but could be anywhere on the continent.  Party has a few paper birds left and want to contact them using that route.  I'm holding their feet to the fire about its flight speed and the fact it is just paper (storms effect, etc.), but otherwise I'm willing for them to get several days/weeks in-game time with a coin-flip there message even gets there.

The other issue is they want to try and increase their odds with some kind of durability or protection addition onto the bird – specifically for the aforementioned weather.  Anything come to mind?  We ended session with their decision and will pick up there next meet.

Answer (score 6):

### A [Paper Bird](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/paper-bird) is sufficiently sturdy; don't punish players for using their limited resources.

A [Paper Bird](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/paper-bird) is a magic item. Magic items have [Magic Item Resilience](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#MagicItemResilience) which makes them

> objects of extraordinary artisanship, [...] Thanks to this
> combination of careful crafting and magical reinforcement, a magic
> item is at least as durable as a regular item of its kind. Most magic
> items, other than potions and scrolls, have resistance to all damage. [...]

The [Paper Bird](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/paper-bird) is neither a scroll nor a potion.

> The bird is an object that has 1 hit point, an Armor Class of 13, a
> flying speed of 60 feet,

Regular weather should be no obstacle for the [Paper Bird](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/paper-bird)

> It travels to within 5 feet of its intended recipient by the most
> direct route, whereupon it turns into a nonmagical and inanimate sheet
> of parchment that can be unfolded only by the intended recipient. If
> the bird’s hit points or speed is reduced to 0 or if it is otherwise
> immobilized, it turns into ash.

So the issues arise when something threatens to attack or immobilise the [Paper Bird](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/paper-bird) while the party that has no better way to contact an NPC via spells like [sending](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sending) - with its unlimited range - is unlikely to have access to any methods that add further protection to the [Paper Bird](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/paper-bird). Nor is it likely that they could keep up with its flying speed of 60 feet that is not subject to [exhaustion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Exhaustion) and doesn't need [resting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Resting), so chasing and protecting the [Paper Bird](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/paper-bird) is also not an option.

But as you stated, they have access to multiple of them - initially, one would assume 1d6 + 3. So if they are willing to spend them as resources, it is likely that some or one of them will eventually reach the NPC.

If I were the DM, I would collaborate with their idea and acknowledge their effort, unless there is a more interesting development along the path. Taking away limited resources like magical items without them paying off is frustrating for players, so I wouldn't recommend doing that. Moving the story towards what is compelling for the players creates a cooperative and more invested experience for all of you.

Comment: Absolutely this. It already is a kinda niche and weird item which is easily outclassed by a lot of (not even that high level) spells, so just let it do its job. Maybe grill them on the (imho short) 50 word limit, or that it may take the bird a week to reach the NPC, but let it go through!

Answer (score 2):

If your group contains a cleric, the cleric can contact this NPC instantly by casting the third-level cleric spell *sending*, which sends a 25-word message to "a creature with which [the caster is] familiar", and lets them reply.  If the NPC is famous, your group might also be able to find an NPC cleric who can cast this spell.

If your group does not have access to third-level spells yet, there don't appear to be any first- or second- level spells that would preserve this item.  Spells that last for multiple days are quite rare in 5e, so we should expect that no spell for this would exist below third level.  I like Allan's suggestion of applying wax to the paper, but you as DM would have to rule on how well it works.

The thing you're doing -- "holding their feet to the fire about it's flight speed and the fact it is just paper" -- seems to me like you're creating unnecessary trivial difficulties.  In my experience, my players are happier if I avoid nitpicking their ability to perform simple tasks, so I try to handwave the minor details and focus on giving them more interesting challenges instead.

My suggestion is that you let them send the message without nitpicking, and agree that the NPC will receive the message in an appropriate amount of time, since that is what the magic item is designed to do.  By the time the group is able to get a response from the NPC after contacting them in this way, they will probably be high enough level that they can cast *sending* anyway and it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm pretty sure that weather is irrelevant for a paper bird. Nothing in the description says that weather will have any effect on the item. It is magical after all and 5E has a general guideline that everything works how the rules say they do.

As for increasing the odds of success, I'd suggest treating the paper with something to make it more waterproof like wax.

Comment: I'd reference DMG p. 141 (Magic Item Resilience) for generic statements about magic item durability. "A magic item is at least as durable as a nonmagical item of its kind." I don't know anything about these paper birds, but nonmagical paper birds generally aren't that durable.